Discrepancy of a sample on Latin Hypercube Sampling
I'm currently working on Design of Experiments (DoE) in order to obtain data to, later on, make some FEM simulations. The starting point is: we want to make those simulations (that depends on some parameters) that will give us the data, but we want to maximize the coverage of the parameter space (dimension $<10$). So we have to decide which parameter values we take with a pre-defined number of parameters with lower and upper bounds for them (i.e. $P_1\in [3,10]$ , $P_2\in [0,2.5]$, $P_3\in [15,23]$ etc). To sum up, we need to sample the space of parameters, so we choose Latin Hypercube Sampling (with a post-reescale).
The problem beggins we we have to decide which sample (of different or equal size) is the appropriate or the best. I am using Quasi-Monte Carlo submodule of SciPy (scipy.stats.qmc), that allows us to compute the discrepancy of a sample. The question is: which is a "good" value for the discrepancy of a sample? This is a knowledge we can't obtain a posteriori, since running multiple batches of differents sizes of fem simulations is extremely time consuming.
So I'm looking for some guide of discrepancy values that can be considered acceptable, for instance, with sampling size bewteen 35 and 45 I can obtain a discrepancy of the order of $10^{-3}$ (i.e. $0.008$) meanwhile increasing sampling size to approx. 150 the discrepancy is of the order of $10^{-4}$ (i.e. $0.0007$). Maybe $0.01$ is a good discrepancy in general, but I couldn't found any fundation on this, I checked some books and articles but are just mathematical development of sampling related concepts.

One approach to determining a good discrepancy would be to sample random Latin hypercubes, find the distribution of discrepancies, and then determine what a good discrepancy would be for that size of sample.
require(lhs)
#> Loading required package: lhs
require(DiceDesign)
#> Loading required package: DiceDesign

set.seed(1043903)

# start with 40 LHC samples

res <- replicate(100, {
  X <- lhs::randomLHS(40, 3)
  return(DiceDesign::discrepancyCriteria(X))
})

# what is a good discrepancy?  Below the bottom 10% of a random LHS?
dis_l2 <- unlist(res[2,])
hist(dis_l2, xlab = "L2 Discrepancy", main = "")


c(min(dis_l2), quantile(dis_l2, prob = 0.10))
#>                     10% 
#> 0.006729422 0.007073103

# example of a better design.  Is it on the lower side of random?
X <- lhs::improvedLHS(40, 3, dup = 5)
DiceDesign::discrepancyCriteria(X)$DisL2
#> [1] 0.00656788

# change to 150 LHC samples

res2 <- replicate(100, {
  X <- lhs::randomLHS(150, 3)
  return(DiceDesign::discrepancyCriteria(X))
})

# what is a good discrepancy?  Below the bottom 10% of a random LHS?
dis_l2 <- unlist(res2[2,])
hist(dis_l2, xlab = "L2 Discrepancy", main = "")


c(min(dis_l2), quantile(dis_l2, prob = 0.10))
#>                     10% 
#> 0.003426497 0.003611993

# example of a better design.  Is it on the lower side of random?
X <- lhs::improvedLHS(150, 3, dup = 5)
DiceDesign::discrepancyCriteria(X)$DisL2
#> [1] 0.002626217

Created on 2024-07-24 with reprex v2.1.1
